# How to add enum field in postgres?

Tags: spring, postgresql

In my model there is an enum field, trying to add an enum field to the database, but does not work, can you comment?

```
public class ChatMessage {
private MessageType messageType;
private String content;
private String sender;

public enum MessageType {
    CHAT,
    JOIN,
    LEAVE
}
```

my postgre code

```
CREATE TYPE messageType AS ENUM ('CHAT', 'JOIN', 'LEAVE');
CREATE TABLE "chatMessage" (
id   SERIAL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY,
messageType messageType,
content VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
sender VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
```

I suppose that I incorrectly declare the variable enum in postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Enumerated Annotation and Spring will handle this for you.
But in general Enums will be VARCHAR(X) in Postgres (see second link)

```
public class ChatMessage {
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private MessageType messageType;
    private String content;
    private String sender;
}
```

http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/jpa-enumerated/

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-an-enum-type-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: CREATE TYPE messageType AS ENUM ('CHAT', 'JOIN', 'LEAVE'); do not use?

Comment: You can try this. But you need to check if Spring JPA is fine with this.
It is possible that @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) is also triggering creating an enum type. I would jpa create your database.

Comment: If your Enum will be extended in your Java Entity it could be necessary to edit your postgres enum type as well. Let JPA manage it...

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, [according to the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html) your doing fine.

Although in their example they choose a different name for the column that references the Enum Type. 
Try change it, like, `messages messageType`.

Another example: https://tapoueh.org/blog/2018/05/postgresql-data-types-enum/#postgresql-enum-data-type